# *ng2For not working and no error messages logged in console

Tags: arrays, angular, ngfor

I ran through many questions which had ngFor not working I tried all the suggestions as below, but nothing seemed to work me.

- Imported {CommonModule} in my "app.component.ts"
- Also tried importing it in my "app.module.ts"
- Check if my array is something like this myArray = [ ] an not myArray :[ ];

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { FileSelectDirective, FileDropDirective } from 'ng2-file-upload';
import { Ng2DragDropModule } from 'ng2-drag-drop';
import {DndModule} from 'ng2-dnd';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { routing } from './app.routing';
import { AppConfig } from './app.config';

import { AlertComponent } from './_directives/index';
import { AuthGuard } from './_guards/index';
import { AlertService, AuthenticationService, UserService, SchemaService } from './_services/index';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/index';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/index';
import { UploadComponent } from './upload/index';
import { ReadComponent } from './read/index';
import { DragComponent } from './drag/index';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        DndModule.forRoot(),
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        routing,
        Ng2DragDropModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        AlertComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        LoginComponent,
        RegisterComponent,
        FileSelectDirective,
        UploadComponent,
        ReadComponent,
        DragComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        AppConfig,
        AuthGuard,
        AlertService,
        AuthenticationService,
        UserService,
        SchemaService
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FileUploader } from 'ng2-file-upload';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent { }
```

**home.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from '../_models/index';
import { UserService } from '../_services/index';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    template: `<h1>{{welcome}}</h1>
                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Game</th>
                        <th>Platform</th> 
                        <th>Release</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr *ngFor="let game of games; let i = index">
                        <td>{{i + 1}}</td>
                        <td>{{game.game}}</td>
                        <td>{{game.platform}}</td>
                        <td>{{game.release}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>`
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

welcome : string;
    games : [{
        game: string,
        platform : string,
        release : string
    }];

    currentUser: User;
    users: User[] = [];

    constructor(private userService: UserService) {
        this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));

        this.welcome = "Display List using ngFor in Angular 2"

        this.games = [{
            game : "Deus Ex: Mankind Divided",
            platform: " Xbox One, PS4, PC",
            release : "August 23"
        },
        {
            game : "Hue",
            platform: " Xbox One, PS4, Vita, PC",
            release : "August 23"
        },
        {
            game : "The Huntsman: Winter's Curse",
            platform: "PS4",
            release : "August 23"
        },
        {
            game : "The Huntsman: Winter's Curse",
            platform: "PS4",
            release : "August 23"
        },
        {
            game : "Deus Ex: Mankind Divided",
            platform: " Xbox One, PS4, PC",
            release : "August 23"
        },
        {
            game : "Hue",
            platform: " Xbox One, PS4, Vita, PC",
            release : "August 23"
        },
        {
            game : "The Huntsman: Winter's Curse",
            platform: "PS4",
            release : "August 23"
        },
        {
            game : "The Huntsman: Winter's Curse",
            platform: "PS4",
            release : "August 23"
        },
        {
            game : "Deus Ex: Mankind Divided",
            platform: " Xbox One, PS4, PC",
            release : "August 23"
        },
        {
            game : "Hue",
            platform: " Xbox One, PS4, Vita, PC",
            release : "August 23"
        },
        {
            game : "The Huntsman: Winter's Curse",
            platform: "PS4",
            release : "August 23"
        },
        {
            game : "The Huntsman: Winter's Curse",
            platform: "PS4",
            release : "August 23"
        },
        {
            game : "Deus Ex: Mankind Divided",
            platform: " Xbox One, PS4, PC",
            release : "August 23"
        },
        {
            game : "Hue",
            platform: " Xbox One, PS4, Vita, PC",
            release : "August 23"
        },
        {
            game : "The Huntsman: Winter's Curse",
            platform: "PS4",
            release : "August 23"
        },
        {
            game : "The Huntsman: Winter's Curse",
            platform: "PS4",
            release : "August 23"
        },
        {
            game : "Deus Ex: Mankind Divided",
            platform: " Xbox One, PS4, PC",
            release : "August 23"
        },
        {
            game : "Hue",
            platform: " Xbox One, PS4, Vita, PC",
            release : "August 23"
        },
        {
            game : "The Huntsman: Winter's Curse",
            platform: "PS4",
            release : "August 23"
        },
        {
            game : "The Huntsman: Winter's Curse",
            platform: "PS4",
            release : "August 23"
        }]
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.loadAllUsers();
    }

    deleteUser(_id: string) {
        this.userService.delete(_id).subscribe(() => { this.loadAllUsers() });
    }

    private loadAllUsers() {
        this.userService.getAll().subscribe(users => { this.users = users; });
    }


}
```

**Output:**

## Game    Platform    Release

**Elements:**
[image: Elements]

**Console Window Screenshot**
[image]

Comment: So your welcome message is also not displaying? Your component does not have a selector. Where/how do you load this component?

Comment: @echonax.. This component is loaded on route after i login into the application.. The problem here is the table headers are displaying correctly as you can see in the Output, but the tbody contents are not

Comment: I don't see any table headers in the picture nor the `h1` elements content

Comment: @echonax.. **# The Game Platform Release**, this is the output which is being displayed.. But i dont see the welcome message or the games array being loaded :(

Comment: That may be because it is hardcoded. However, none of your interpolation fields work at all. I think you are forgetting something essential in your question.

Comment: @echonax.. Exaclty .. none of my interpolation seems to be working, any idea what I might be missing?

Comment: I just tried displaying {{1+1}} , and this indeed returns a 2 is getting displayed.. But i dont know why the welcome string or arrays are not getting displayed

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of your console also? With the filter tab

Comment: Would be weird if that's the problem, but you are using `templateUrl` for a template string. You should use just `template`. But I would expect a completely different error

Comment: @PierreDuc that's a great catch :-)

Comment: @echonax.. I changed it to just template earlier in my code and checked, but still no luck

Comment: @MohammedJunaid can you reproduce the issue on a plunker?

Comment: Could you include your app html template too please

Comment: When i checked my home.component.js file it seems to not be updating , any reason why? And thats the reason none of my changes in the "home.component.ts" file have an effect

Comment: @MohammedJunaid Well, that's indeed the only logical explanation. I would guess you should change your `tsconfig.json`, or use the `angular-cli` for development. If you are already using the cli, I remember there was an issue a while back with changes not being updated. So again my advise to update to the latest angular version, and with it, the latest angular-cli version

Comment: @PierreDuc..Am new to Angular2, so can you explain what you mean by changing my `tsconfig.json` and can you point me to any links of how I can use `angular-cli` for my current project?

Answer (score 0):

in home.component.ts

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
selector:'app-home'
    templateUrl: `<h1>{{welcome}}</h1>
})
```

and put above selector in your 'app.component.html',

in app.component.html

```
<h1>This is app.component.html</h1>
<app-home></app-home>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but i guess this wont help either, as the table headers "# Game Platform Release" are displaying but the games and welcome message are not .. Thats where am stuck

Comment: in angular 2.0 and above (4 also) ngfor structure is change .            Previous structure :ngFor # game of games....present structure:ngFor let game of games

Comment: [linkl](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#hooks-overview)  don't put complex logic in constructor

Comment: I just tried displaying {{1+1}} , and this indeed returns a 2 is getting displayed.. But i dont know why the welcome string or arrays are not getting displayed

Comment: @harish seems to work there. Perhaps try to update to the latest stable version of angular (4.1.3). I see you are using a version from a couple months ago

Comment: One weird thing that's happening is no matter what I change in the home.component.ts its displaying the same output, and only changes in the home.component.html files are reflecting.. Any idea why this seems to be happening? for eg: If I remove the templateUrl from the .ts file , still the Output is the same .

Comment: @PierreDuc When i checked my home.component.js file it seems to not be updating , any reason why? And thats the reason none of my changes in the "home.component.ts" file have an effect

Answer (score 0):

Use `ngOnInit()` lifecycle callback to initialized the fields.

Try below code:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    welcome : string;
    games : [{
        game: string,
        platform : string,
        release : string
      }];

    currentUser: User;
    users: User[] = [];

    ngOnInit() {
      this.loadAllUsers();

      this.welcome = "Display List using ngFor in Angular 2"

        this.games = [{
            game : "Deus Ex: Mankind Divided",
            platform: " Xbox One, PS4, PC",
            release : "August 23"
        },
        {
            game : "Hue",
            platform: " Xbox One, PS4, Vita, PC",
            release : "August 23"
        },
        {
            game : "The Huntsman: Winter's Curse",
            platform: "PS4",
            release : "August 23"
        },
        {
            game : "The Huntsman: Winter's Curse",
            platform: "PS4",
            release : "August 23"
        },
        {
            game : "Deus Ex: Mankind Divided",
            platform: " Xbox One, PS4, PC",
            release : "August 23"
        },
        {
            game : "Hue",
            platform: " Xbox One, PS4, Vita, PC",
            release : "August 23"
        },
        {
            game : "The Huntsman: Winter's Curse",
            platform: "PS4",
            release : "August 23"
        },
        {
            game : "The Huntsman: Winter's Curse",
            platform: "PS4",
            release : "August 23"
        },
        {
            game : "Deus Ex: Mankind Divided",
            platform: " Xbox One, PS4, PC",
            release : "August 23"
        },
        {
            game : "Hue",
            platform: " Xbox One, PS4, Vita, PC",
            release : "August 23"
        },
        {
            game : "The Huntsman: Winter's Curse",
            platform: "PS4",
            release : "August 23"
        },
        {
            game : "The Huntsman: Winter's Curse",
            platform: "PS4",
            release : "August 23"
        },
        {
            game : "Deus Ex: Mankind Divided",
            platform: " Xbox One, PS4, PC",
            release : "August 23"
        },
        {
            game : "Hue",
            platform: " Xbox One, PS4, Vita, PC",
            release : "August 23"
        },
        {
            game : "The Huntsman: Winter's Curse",
            platform: "PS4",
            release : "August 23"
        },
        {
            game : "The Huntsman: Winter's Curse",
            platform: "PS4",
            release : "August 23"
        },
        {
            game : "Deus Ex: Mankind Divided",
            platform: " Xbox One, PS4, PC",
            release : "August 23"
        },
        {
            game : "Hue",
            platform: " Xbox One, PS4, Vita, PC",
            release : "August 23"
        },
        {
            game : "The Huntsman: Winter's Curse",
            platform: "PS4",
            release : "August 23"
        },
        {
            game : "The Huntsman: Winter's Curse",
            platform: "PS4",
            release : "August 23"
        }]
    }



   constructor(private userService: UserService) {
        this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
   }

 deleteUser(_id: string) {
        this.userService.delete(_id).subscribe(() => { this.loadAllUsers() });
    }

    private loadAllUsers() {
        this.userService.getAll().subscribe(users => { this.users = users; });
    }


}
```